# how to move the done button to the right in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

So i want to move my done button to the right of toolbar.

here is my code:-

i appreciate all answers

```
let picker=UIDatePicker()
func createDatePicker() {
   let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    // done button for toolbar
    let done = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))
    toolbar.setItems([done], animated: false)

    tanggalLahirTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    tanggalLahirTextField.inputView = picker
    picker.datePickerMode = .date
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add flexible space on left side, so your done button will automatically move to right side. Update your code as follows:

```
let done = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))

// Add this line of code.   
let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

toolbar.setItems([flexibleSpace, done], animated: false)
```

Comment: @IndraSen, Pleasure to help you. Accept it due to work for you.